# How to create `.u3d` files?

Tags: c++, 3d, gnuplot, u3d

I'm working on a project for school and I've got some 3D vector data as well as surface plots. These are saved in `.dat` files outputted from a `c++` program.

I'm able to plot these files in `gnuplot` as wanted, but I'd really like to make `.u3d` files so I can include them in a TeX document (using the `movie15`package).

How do I create u3d files? (I'm working on mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/), as it can import common 3D file formats, and exports U3D files.

From the main page:

- imports: PLY, STL, OFF, OBJ, 3DS, COLLADA, PTX, V3D, PTS, APTS, XYZ, GTS, TRI, ASC, X3D, X3DV, VRML, ALN.
- exports: PLY, STL, OFF, OBJ, 3DS, COLLADA, VRML, DXF, GTS, **U3D**, IDTF, X3D

Since that software can be used from command line to process files, the idea would be to generate a file using one of the formats it imports (for example, a X3D or PLY, both can be used to represent vector data and point sets) and let Meshlab convert it to U3D trough the command line.

Comment: the problem is I only have a .dat file, which lists the points in XYZ coordinates. I don't know any of these formats.

Comment: If you only have points, the conversion of your .dat file to a .PLY file would then be trivial since that ASCII format was principally designed to store three dimensional data from 3D scanners. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_%28file_format%29. As a side note, Meshlab supports quite well the "Points cloud" data type imported from .PLY files.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/u3d/) is a library on Sourceforge for working with the u3d format. 
This just came up on a quick search, never tried it so I cannot provide 
more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia cites [several applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_3D#Application_support) can create .u3d files. Here are [the specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-363.htm) for all four versions of the u3d file format.